# Colour-coding get-content results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got a powershell script that monitors a log file, filters out the interesting bits and then presents those bits to me as and when they are written to the file. Works wonderfully. The line of interest is:

```
get-content "$logFile" -wait | where { select-string $searchTerm -inp $_ }
```

Now I want to get fancy!

I would like the font colour to change everytime a particular term is encountered. I can set the font colour easily enough, but how would you do it on-the-fly with the above statement?

**Edit:** Figured it out, but can't post an answer for 8 hours. Will upload it tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Get-Content $logFile -Wait |
  Select-String $searchTerm | 
  ForEach {write-host -ForegroundColor red $_.line}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking for something that provides *selective* color coding, then try something like this.

First, set up a helper function to select an appropriate color:

```
function Get-LogColor {
    Param([Parameter(Position=0)]
    [String]$LogEntry)

    process {
        if ($LogEntry.Contains("DEBUG")) {Return "Green"}
        elseif ($LogEntry.Contains("WARN")) {Return "Yellow"}
        elseif ($LogEntry.Contains("ERROR")) {Return "Red"}
        else {Return "White"}
    }
}
```

Then execute a line that looks like this:

```
gc -wait $logFile | ForEach {Write-Host -ForegroundColor (Get-LogColor $_) $_}
```

Comment: Your answer is more specific, to what i want. It works, but also it is printing the following error randomly:

`Get-LogColor : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LogEntry' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:156
+ ...  (Get-LogColor $_) $_}
+                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-LogColor], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Get-LogColor`

Comment: I haven't seen your source data, but I can only assume that there are empty lines in your log file, which technically would break the 'Mandatory=$true' binding rule. I've removed this in my answer; The only consequence is that your blank log file lines will be passed right back to the console, but this would have happened with a vanilla "Get-Content (gc)" statement anyway.

Comment: thnkx, now its working fine.
this should be the accepted answer