# PowerShell, Display My TXT Log file with different Colors:

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-2.0

I am C# developer, and I use `Log4Net` logger for Logging my .NET Applications.

I have a log file at my Server. I use:

```
get-content filepath -wait
```

to continuously monitor my logs and exceptions.

It works fine, now I want to display the `Log.txt` file content in different colors.
I mean if an exception occurs in code, the logger writes it the `Log.txt` file like:

`Exception: An error has occured.` I want powersehll to display that line in `fore red`

I am New to PowerShell, i tried this:

get-content \devvm01\C$\inetpub\CRMCustomPages\Logger\globalrescuedevlog.txt -Wait |Select-String "Info" | ForEach {write-host -ForegroundColor green $_.line}

but this will only print info Messages with green color, 
I think I am doing this wrong.
Please advice how can i achieve the required functionality. It sounds simple, but i cant figure it out.

**EDIT:** 
tried this

```
get-content \\devvm01\C$\inetpub\CRMCustomPages\Logger\globalrescuedevlog.txt -Wait |Select-String "Info" | ForEach {write-host -ForegroundColor green $_.line}
```

But it will print only Info messages, I want to print all messages along with info like Debug, Exception etc

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132140/colour-coding-get-content-results

Comment: Can you provide the full code of how you try to print the content of this file?

Comment: I answered this question more specifically on the question @DavidBrabant  posted a link too... without realizing these questions were linked. I use log4net as well, AND monitor using PS consoles, so the code examples listed in the linked question are geared specifically for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following:

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
```

This should give you some ideas.  You could use a

```
switch -regex
```

to change the foreground color based on the content of the string.