# ccze alternative for powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

there is this cool tool that colorify a log, I'm looking for an alternative in PowerShell, I am googling like a week but didn't find any result. any chance there is an alternative for this?

[ccze description](https://howchoo.com/g/mzm3ztdhm2u/how-to-colorize-your-logs-with-ccze)

couple of other tools that doesnt' help much but do the same

[lnav](http://lnav.org/)

[colortail](https://github.com/joakim666/colortail)

[lch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-color-highlight)

Comment: Pretty good solution provided in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132140/colour-coding-get-content-results

Comment: but I need to it manually, like creating 100 type of syntax coloring regex. I'm looking for a ready to use solution.